# How to call contract state-changing method on Ropsten via Infura using web3@1.0.0?

Tags: contract-development, web3js, contract-invocation, ropsten, infura

I have the following contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Escrow {

    address public owner;

    event LogReceivedFunds(address sender, uint amount);
    event LogReturnedFunds(address recipient, uint amount);

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() public payable {
        emit LogReceivedFunds(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function refundBalance() public onlyOwner {
        uint256 balance = address(this).balance;
        msg.sender.transfer(balance);
        emit LogReturnedFunds(msg.sender, balance);
    }

    function kill() public onlyOwner {
        selfdestruct(owner);
    }
}
```

I successfully connected to Ropsten via Infura, as I can:

1. Deploy the contract via truffle
2. Run `call` on methods such as `getBalance`.

However, when I want to use [send](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-send) to alter the state (that is, refund the owner of the contract their deposited funds), I get this response:

> Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: ""

This doesn't happen on Ganache, therefore I reckon it's a problem caused by Infura. Is there some sort of incompatibility?

Comment: The `refundBalance` function has the `onlyOwner` tag attached to it. When you are using infura, are you properly unlocking the owner account to access the contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infura doesn't support any operation that requires a private key (such as signing a transaction). This is because they don't store anybody's private key.

If you want to send a transaction via Infura, you have to sign it locally first (using your private key) and then broadcast the signed transaction via Infura.

Comment: Can you post an example how to prepare and sign a transaction that makes a changing-state contract call with arguments, please?

Comment: @kitsune you can find that in this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/Contractz). Check out the `js` folder.